# No Compatible GPUs RTX 3080 Windows 10

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, drivers

I already tried to reinstall Windows using the keep files and apps method. Still no joy. Already tried switch between drivers (471.96)

Could someone please help?

[image]

Comment: Try other driver versions maybe.

Comment: What Blender version are you using?

Comment: I've already tried other driver versions but still cant use the optiX, I've tried both blender-2.83.17-stable and blender-3.0.0-alpha. Do you think i need to reinstall my windows 10 to fix the issue?

Comment: Did you install CUDA drivers?

Comment: Hi @Crantisz, yes I've installed the latest CUDA drivers already 11.4

Comment: Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date..

Comment: Hi @ChristopherBennett, Yes already up to date for all the Drivers. Do you think I need to reinstall my windows 10 for this?

Comment: I don't think a windows re-install is necessary (maybe as a last resort). I only mentioned it because I know for a fact that out of date drivers can cause "no compatible GPU's" to be found by blender.

Comment: Hi there Everyone, thanks for supporting me. Good news! I already found the answer. I Had to wipe clean my windows 10 and get a Fresh clean install and voilaaa the optix options is there..Thank youuu guyss

Answer (score 1):

Wipe Out my windows and get a clean and fresh installation on Windows. update with the latest Nvidia Drivers, and OptiX drivers and voilaaa problem solved. The Optix option now can be selected in the Edit-Preferences-System-Cycles render devices - OPTIX[image]